# Rotating 1bpp bitmap data

Tags: c, image, winapi

I have some allocated space in memory holding a bitmap image's data. It's 1 bit per pixel, so  the first byte's most significant bit corresponds to the top-left's first pixel's status (on or off).

The image's dimensions are 256x224, and I'm displaying it inside a window by using the Win32 api's StretchDIBits function like this:

```
    StretchDIBits(
        dc,
        0, 0, 224, 256, // Destination (x, y, w, h)
        0, 0, 224, 256, // Source (x, y, w, h)
        imageData,
        bmInfo,
        DIB_RGB_COLORS,
        SRCCOPY
);
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how I can rotate this image data clockwise by 90 degrees. This seems like it would be more straightforward if the dimensions were equal on both sides (if the image was a square), but they are not.

Also, since the image is 1bpp, I believe this means I can't just move the bytes around and need to actually move the bits individually. I can't figure out how I would do this, and efficiently enough, since the function implementing this would have to be ran 60 times per second.

Comment: You can draw the image rotated with GDI+, or use `SetWorldTransform` and other GDI functions. Or you can make a copy of the bitmap that's rotated. It's not clear which way you want to go.

Comment: I tried using `SetWorldTransform` to rotate it 90 degrees, the result is a blurry output: https://i.imgur.com/G70yesl.png (this is supposed to be legible text, which it is without the rotation)

Comment: *"I can't figure out how I would do this, and efficiently enough, since the function implementing this would have to be ran 60 times per second."* - This is a 224x256 px bitmap. You don't have to worry about performance. You may want to consider, that rotating by 90° can be expressed as a sequence of 2 reflections.